# Excel VBA Get Count of Non-Empty Rows in Range

Tags: vba, excel

I know this has been asked at least a dozen times, but of all those questions the solutions seemed to be tailored or simply created an error in my code. For some reason I get an error when I try and reference a range from a different worksheet. Below is my code. I have two worksheets (tabs). One has a button to launch my code `MENU`, the other is the data I am trying to read and write to `RAW`. All I am trying to do is find out how many rows of data the sheet has so I can loop through the rows and make changes. For some reason I can't wrap my head around it or something.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
  Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet

  Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.Worksheets("RAW")

  Dim i As Long
  Dim siteCol As Long

  siteCol = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 1 To siteCol
    wsCurrent.Range("I" & i) = "MARKED"
  Next i
  Range("I1") = siteCol
End Sub
```

Comment: All of your `... As Integer` should be `... As Long` - Integer only goes to ~32,000  Your code has issues unless the data on "RAW" always begins at row 1 and has no gaps.

Comment: Change it, still getting Error 6 for Overflow. Tim, could you elaborate on the second half?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is it that you are trying to do? Your code as written will return an error if there are more than about `2^15` entries in column I.  And then it will fill in, starting a I1, the word `MARKED` depending on the number of entries originally in Column I.

Comment: If you had data in **I10:I19** then `CountA("I:I")` would return 10, but your loop would be working on **I1:I10**

Comment: There are 41855 rows in this sheet. I am getting Error 6 for Overflow, which will go away if I don't reference the RAW sheet. New to VBA coming from Google Script which feels like it made a heck of a lot more sense.

Comment: Makes sense Tim, however I am starting from 1 in this case. I do see your point though and there are no gaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- Always use `Long` for your variables, not `Integer` unless you have a specific reason. The maximum value of an `Integer` is **32767**, which might be not enough to hold your count of rows.

2- Dont get the number of rows with `COUNTA`, this has many drawbacks. use this instead:

```
siteCol = wsCurrent.Range("I" & wsCurrent.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This finds the Row number of the last occupied cell in `wsCurrent`, assuming that `wsCurrent` is at the top of the document (it starts on Row 1). Please note that if wsCurrent is completely empty, this will find the row number of the first occupied cell *above* `wsCurrent`, or the first row of the document.

3- When you want to assign a whole range to the same value, you can do it at once, which is much faster and simpler, like this (no loop needed):

```
wsCurrent.Range("I1:I" & siteCol) = "MARKED"
```

4- No need to `Activate` a worksheet to work with it. Drop the statement `wsCurrent.Activate` and try to always work with qualified ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I am still getting an Error 6 Overflow when I run it. Seems to be linked to calling the wsCurrent on the Range.

Comment: @xxSithRagexx Did you make all these modifications? did you `Dim i as Long`? why dont you edit your code to show the complete sub?

Comment: Qualify your ranges: `siteCol = wsCurrent.Range("I" & wsCurrent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`